# iPhone TableView Data Into 2 Sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I am trying to get a tableview to split data i have in an array into sections...

I'm pretty new to this but below is my code snippet

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    if(section == 0) 
    {
        contentArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Send SMS", @"Reports", nil] retain];
    }
    if(section == 1) 
    {
        contentArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Accounts", nil] retain];
    }

    return [contentArray count];
}
```

I have split the data successfully into the 2 sections but when populating the rows It just repeats the first content array in both sections.

Can any one help...

Thanks

Comment: Can you post code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: In your sample code you are going to have lots memory leak.  It's best to create the array in viewDidLoad for example.  Because you will need access to the array in a few methods.  See the answer by @fluchtpunkt.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you have a leak in the code you presented. Remove the two calls to `retain`.

Second, you are in the classic problem of having multiple switches/if..else chains based on the same information. This screams for an OO solution.

First create a TableSection class:

```
@interface TableSection : NSObject
{ }
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* header;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray* rows;

- (NSInteger)numberOfRows;
- (UITableViewCell*)cellInTableView: (UITableView*)tableView forRow: (NSInteger)row;

@end

@implementation TableSection
@synthesize header;
@synthesize rows;
- (void)dealloc {
    [header release];
    [rows release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRows {
    return rows.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)cellInTableView: (UITableView*)tableView forRow: (NSInteger)row {
    // create/reuse, setup and return a UITableViewCell
}

@end
```

Now in your TableViewController

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
{ }
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* tableSections;

@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)dealloc {
    [tableSections release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    TableSection* section1 = [[TableSection alloc] init];
    [section1 setRows: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Send SMS", @"Reports", nil]];
    TableSectlion* section2 = [[TableSection alloc] init];
    [section2 setRows: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Accounts", nil]];
    [self setTableSections: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: section1, section2, nil]];
    [section2 release];
    [section1 release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTableSections: nil];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView*)tableView {
    return self.tableSections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.tableSections objectAtIndex: section] numberOfRows];
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return [[self.tableSections objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] cellInTableView: tableView forRow: indexPath.row];
}

- (NSString*)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.tableSections objectAtIndex: section] header];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

don't switch (and leak) your content data in one of the tableview datasource or delegate methods. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` can be called an arbitrary number of times. With your code you are relying on a particular order in which those methods are called.

You should have a separate array for each section (or one array that holds the two section arrays)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0) {
        return [section0Array count];
    }
    if(section == 1) {
        return [section1Array count];
    }
    return 0;

}
```

And you could create those arrays in viewDidLoad:

```
section0Array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Send SMS", @"Reports", nil] retain];
section1Array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Accounts", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  method is also returning the correct cells based on your splitting of the content array. You can do the similar check in the method something like

```
switch(indexPath.section) 
{ 
     case 0:  //First Section 
     switch(indexPath.row) 
     {
         case 0: //Setup the cell Send SMS
             break;
         case 1: //Setup the cell Reports
             break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you should put the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath because where you are writting there we generally add the count of rows in each section