# Divide NSMutableArray data into two UITableView Sections - conditionally

Tags: nsmutablearray, uitableview

I have an NSMutableArray filled by external source.
This array is an array of NSDictionaries - which actually contain xml key value pairs within them. Somewhat like:

```
<element1>
  <key1=valueA>
  <key2=valueB>
</element1>
<element2>
  <key1=valueB>
  <key2=valueB>
</element2>
<element3>
  <key1=valueB>
  <key2=valueC>
</element3>
```

And so on.

Now, all my key1=valueB records must go into Section 1 of UITableView.
In above xml, it will be element2 and element3.
And rest should go to section 2.

I know [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351405/iphone-tableview-data-into-2-sections) that advise to create two arrays from beginning, but that filtering is somewhat complex based on above structure. I am seeking something concise, and if possible, in-built UITableView functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that easiest way is to divide into two arrays first. And luckily I figured out how easy it is:

```
   for (NSMutableDictionary *theDict in sourceMutableArray)
   {
     if ([theDict objectForKey:@"key1"] != nil)
     {
       if ([[theDict objectForKey:@"key1"] isEqualToString:@"valueB"])
       {
          [destinationMutableArray1 addObject:theDict];
       }
       else
       {
          [destinationMutableArray2 addObject:theDict];
       }            
     }
   }
```